# Delete documents in Elasticsearch NOT working

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got 20M+ documents to delete from an Index and this code below is not working (the index is called 'suppliers2'):

```
POST suppliers2/_doc/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed&refresh
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Brad

Comment: hey @Brad, do you have any output? Error in response or logs? And - just to have it mentioned - why not to drop the entire index if you want to delete all (assuming you have only this doument type in there)

Comment: Why not simply deleting the index with `DELETE suppliers2` and recreating it afterwards? Much more efficient

Comment: Hi again @ibexit and Val.  Thank you both for replying.  I just did a DELETE suppliers (I had created a new index called just 'suppliers') and it gave me "acknowledged.  Great.  But in Kibana when I go to the Discover section, there are zero documents but he index Suppliers is still listed and on the Management tab as well.